# How to solve this TinyMCE error duing deployemnt in vercel?

Tags: debugging

error during build:
Error: [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "@tinymce/tinymce-react" from "/vercel/path0/blogspurr/src/components/Blogform/TinyMCE.jsx".
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
`build.rollupOptions.external`
at viteWarn (file:///vercel/path0/blogspurr/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:48216:27)
at onwarn (file:///vercel/path0/blogspurr/node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-react/dist/index.mjs:249:9)
at onRollupWarning (file:///vercel/path0/blogspurr/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:48245:9)
at onwarn (file:///vercel/path0/blogspurr/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:47976:13)
at file:///vercel/path0/blogspurr/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24276:13
at Object.logger [as onLog] (file:///vercel/path0/blogspurr/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:25950:9)
at ModuleLoader.handleInvalidResolvedId (file:///vercel/path0/blogspurr/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24862:26)
at file:///vercel/path0/blogspurr/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24822:26
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1

I am using TinyMCE in my app and while deploying this build error arises.